# ImageSource to System.Drawing.Image C#

Tags: c#, image, imagesource

In a C# application I have, I need to add an Imagesource to an existing Bitmap image.

As far as I can see I have to use

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);
g.DrawImage();
```

I get that for g.DrawImage() I have to convert my Imagesource to System.Drawing.Image, my question is how do I do this?

Comment: This is a dupe, but as previously stated, check out:http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/tamir/2007/09/09/how-to-use-imagesource-no-handler-in-winforms-as-systemdrawingbitmap-hbitmap/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert your bitmap to a Graphics. Simply do: `Graphics.DrawImage(myBitmap, myPoint);`
Where myPoint is the coordinate to draw the image at.